# Can't find models on heroku - Adonis Js

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-postgres, adonis.js

I did deployed adonis js API app to Heroku successfully. I can register and login fine but when tried accessing other routes like `products` I get an error `Error: Cannot find module '/app/app/models/Product'`. The api works fine locally. I can't seem to find the cause of the error. I initially thought it could be the issue with autoload on package.json.

Here is my order models

```
'use strict'

/** @type {typeof import('@adonisjs/lucid/src/Lucid/Model')} */
const Model = use('Model')

class Order extends Model {

  static get table() {
    return 'orders'
  }

  static get primaryKey() {
    return 'id'
  }

  user() {
    return this.belongsTo('App/Models/User')
  }

  histories () {
    return this.hasMany('App/Models/History')
  }
}

module.exports = Order
```

And this how I import on OrderController.

```
const Order = use('App/models/Order')
```

Migration output on heroku
[image]

`Heroku logs` results
[image]

When I have `NODE_ENV` as `development`, I get the following error on the browser. 
[image]

Comment: can you do the migration in live ?if yes then put log file of heroku here

Comment: Migration was successful @AmitKadivar. I have updated the post to include migration screenshot.

Comment: can you send me error log of heroku using `heroku logs` this command you view log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in controller your path is wrong 
you need to import like this 
you write `models` instead of writing `Models`

```
const Product = use('App/Models/Product')
```

Comment: This was the issue. Thank you